# In my oracle DB table there are 21 indexes, is that good or bad

Tags: database, oracle, performance

Actually my application faces slowness and while digging the code I found this, please suggest.

Comment: This information by iteslf is inherently neither good nor bad.  When you profile your application's performance, is there any indication that interactions with this one table are the bottleneck?  When you profile queries against this table, what do the execution plans tell you?  Addressing performance issues in an application involves more than just looking through the code and guessing.

Comment: How many of these indexes are used?

Comment: In case they are Bitmap-Indexes it would be rather good.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a lot, but whether it is or not depends heavily on the table structure.
If you've a hundred columns, it may not be a lot of indices.

Of course if you have a hundred columns, your database design is probably pretty bad.

That out of the way, a high number of indices probably leads to poor insert and update performance as all those indices have to be updated with every transaction that hits the table.
Also, you're more likely to face corrupt indices if you have a lot of them, which can/will affect performance.

Anyhow, it's an indication to take a good hard look at your database design and see what can be improved.

But simply blaming your performance issues on the database is not something we can confirm or deny. There are far more factors, network for example (I several years ago had a severe performance problem that was caused neither by the application or the database but by a very slow network in between the application server and database server causing the results of database queries to take 10+ seconds to reach the application server, even if those queries themselves only took milliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, it depends.

Tables with lots of columns might need a lot of indexes. Especially if the table is a crucial one which is referenced by many different queries. On the other hand such a table points towards a poor data model which has been kludged by encrusting the table with indexes instead of addressing the real problem and re-modelling the table into two or more tables.

Generally lots of indexes cause performance with inserts and deletes, and to a lesser extent updates, because all of the affected indexes have to be synchronised. A multiplicity of indexes doesn't necessarily lead to poor SELECT performance. That is, provided your statistics are up to date so the Optimizer is making clever decisions about which index to use. Remember that for some queries the cleverest choice might be to use no index and go for a Full Table Scan.

Beyond that I agree with @david. There's no value in guesses about your particular problem. There are many possible reasons why your *"application faces slowness"*. You need to trace your application to find the bottlenecks. Once you know where it spends most of the time you will know where to start investigating.